# ruby-oembed, Vimeo custom parameters?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oembed, video-embedding

I have a site where I want to be able to upload and embed videos. I use Rails 4 and the `ruby-oembed` gem.

I want to be able to edit some of the parameters for the embed code. In one of my models I have the following code:

```
before_validation { embed_code_from_url self.embed_url}

private 

  def embed_code_from_url(url)
    url = url + "?width=100px"
    resource = OEmbed::Providers::Vimeo.get(url)    
    self.embed_code = resource.html       
  end
```

`OEmbed`seems to ignore the extra parameters. Is it possible to have custom parameters with `OEmbed`, and how could I do that in a rails app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The signature for the #get is `get(url, query = {})`

So, try:

```
resource = OEmbed::Providers::Vimeo.get(url, width: "100px")    
self.embed_code = resource.html
```

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to work. How would it look with multiple parameters? `resource = OEmbed::Providers::Vimeo.get(url,{width: "100%", color: "EA4403",  title: 0, byline: 0, portrait: 0})` results in bad URL. (I have also tried without the {}-signs.

Comment: the "%" in your width is likely getting in the way. try just pixels first.

Comment: Thanks, that worked! Is it possible to use %-somehow? Or maybe inherit?

Comment: I decided to follow the tips on this site: http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/create-fluid-width-videos, to create fluid width instead. Thanks again @Jesse